# Conditional Tag Change in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in metadataGovernance">
            <awsui-control-group validation-message="" label="{{item.governance === 'Required' ? item.tag + '*' : item.tag}}">
                <awsui-textfield name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value"></awsui-textarea>
            </awsui-control-group>
        </div>
```

Here i want to validate each field(item.tag == 'Name of the tag' and should change the field type, for eg.

```
if(item.tag == 'To Database')

<awsui-select name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value">  
</awsui-select>

if(item.tag == 'Description') then it should take the tag as
<awsui-textarea name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value">
</awsui-textarea>
```

based on the name of the tag i should decide the field type in ng-repeat.

Comment: Provide more code and more information, please.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question is very very unclear and might be closed if you don't edit it.

Comment: Sorry i was editing the question.

Comment: Do you know about ng-if? What's preventing you from using a simple `ng-if="item.tag=='To Database'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare a stringvalue in ng-show inside a customdirective?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605145/how-to-compare-a-stringvalue-in-ng-show-inside-a-customdirective)

Comment: Hi, I am new to angular. Can you pls post your answer by editing my main code. It will be clear for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
<awsui-select ng-if="item.tag === 'To Database'" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value">  
</awsui-select>

<awsui-textarea ng-if="item.tag === 'Description'" name="{{item.tag}}" data-disabled="false" ng-model="item.value">
</awsui-textarea>
```