# How to use ngIf condition with a constant and a ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following html file.

```
<p-selectButton
        [options]="metrics"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedMetric"
        (onChange)="onChange($event)"
></p-selectButton>
<p>Selected Metric: {{selectedMetric}}</p>
<div *ngIf="selectedMetric"==="Metric 1">Selected first </div>
```

The above is obviously incorrect.
What is the correct syntax for my ngIf directive if I want to compare 
{{selectedMetric}} and a string constant like "option 1"?

Comment: similar question here .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605145/how-to-compare-a-stringvalue-in-ng-show-inside-a-customdirective

Comment: If you have multiple options, consider `ngSwitch` instead.

Comment: ngSwitch is a great idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div *ngIf="selectedMetric==='Metric 1'">Selected first </div>` should to the trick to compare a variable against a literal string

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, to use a defined constant within your .ts file of the component, and initialize it's that variable's value in the constructor.